# how to redirect to another page in a common header

Tags: java, jsp, filter, jstl

Currently I have three different apps deployed in the same AppServer. Their contexts are  /appPortal, /appPortal/app1, /appPortal/app2

The app1 and app2 both have a common header which includes a jsp from appPortal like

```
<c:import url="/jsps/topHeader.jsp"  context="/appPortal">
```

I tried to add some logic in this topHeader.jsp to redirect the user to another noaccess page who tried to access app1&app2 directly without login in the /appPortal but it doesn't work, and I don't want to add a filter to each application. What can I do, how can I make the redirection works?

Comment: Can you explain the "doesn't work" part?

Comment: The topHeader.jsp has been included in app1 and app2. When I add response.sendRedirect("/appPortal/error.jsp"); to the topHeader.jsp. It doesn't redirect.@KishoreK

Answer (score 0):

Using a filter would be an ideal choice. But if you want to have it in JSP, try to keep the redirection logic before any HTML content is rendered.

Comment: Currently I only have these two apps. But there will be more than 10 modules in the futher, I don't want to add filter for each application.

Answer (score 0):

"forward" and or "dispatcher". Those two words should be of use.

Comment: "forward" doesn't work, but I can use window.location.href='url' in javascript to implement this requirement.